# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How would I make it so my mute command is timed?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have a mute commmand using the following code:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Muted')
  await member.add_roles(role)
  embed=discord.Embed(title="User Muted!", description="**{0}** was muted by **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author), color=random.choice(colors))
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It works fine, but I want to make it so you can specify how long they will be muted for. Not quite sure how to do that.

I am new to programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `await asyncio.sleep()` for the specified time and then remove the role. Make sure to `import asyncio`.

Comment: This would work- but when I use ```time.sleep()```, it ignores any other commands use during the period it is asleep.

Comment: Updating answer to work for your scenario.

Comment: Hmm... now I get this `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: My bad I forgot to add await to the command. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Although `await asyncio.sleep()` is an option, I would not recommend it. The time is saved in the cache and if/when the bot restarts or shuts down, the cache will be wiped the people will stay muted forever. In my opinion the best way to deal with that is to use a database where you store the time when people should be unmuted. Menu Docs has a really [good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyS6DIjMpGY&t) on that, I suggest watching it to get more info.